# the place for simple logic in an angularJS application

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know which is preferable in an angularJS app.

in the html, I can have...

a)

```
<span ng-class="{'car-icon': category === 'CAR' || category === 'SUV','bus-icon': category === 'BUS','bike-icon': category === 'BIKE'}"</span>
```

or...

b)

```
<span ng-class="categoryIcon"></span>
```

where categoryIcon is set in a controller function.

My preference is for b). a) puts logic in the UI which I do not like. I also find it much easier to test controller functions, so another reason for b)

However I'm being told that a) is the way to go because that is what angularJS templating is for. The example is applying CSS styling however I'm getting the same reasoning for setting href's, there is some simple logic required and I'm being asked to do it in the HTML templating vs a controller function.

Comment: I tend to prefer b) when the condition to put on `ng-class` attribute is more complicated than a single comparison. Mainly for readability but also for maintainability, and as you said, logic do not have to be on the UI.

Comment: It depends. If it's an operation that you want to happen with every digest cycle, it definitely needs to be in the template, however, if it's something very light like a basic conditional, doing it in the template won't have any real performance drawbacks, only maintainability. but, at the same time, I wouldn't want to clutter my controller with some one off logic that is only needed by the template for presentation purposes.

Comment: For example, a basic collapsible panel can be built entirely within the template without the controller needing to know about it.

Comment: @KevinB perhaps my example is not the  greatest. Collapsible panel I think I would agree. In other examples, I need to build a url that's conditionally  based on data coming from the middle tier. The CSS decision is also based on data coming from the middle tier. Using the a) way has the potential to get out of hand and be less maintainable, as MattDionis pointed out, as new categories are added. For what its worth the a) example is already in two places in the app.

Comment: I prefer a solution similar to what @MichaelOrl is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of preference, but I much prefer option b)

`<span ng-class="categoryIcon">` with `categoryIcon` set in the controller.

If you think ahead, what if new categories are added, that html is going to get long, ugly, and error prone. Also, what if you want to use `categoryIcon` in multiple places in your html in the future. Simply referencing `ng-class="categoryIcon"` is much better design than copying option a) to multiple places.

Comment: why it's downvoated ?

Comment: Since it's just an opinion, i guess anyone can decide it's right or wrong and be correct.

Comment: Why I marked this as the answer: This is a best/better practices question, so you may not agree with this. This practice allows the logic to be removed from the UI, and be encapsulated in the controller. The logic can grow over time with no change  to the  UI. This is also more reusable, in the future if you need to change the logic you need to do it in only one place, the controller.  No one mentioned testing, but I find testing a controller simple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the other answers here have been down voted, since this is an opinion on best practices and there is no concrete right/wrong answers, but I would prefer solution A in one-off usages, and a solution hinting at B when it has to be repeated in the view.

I tend to think that the view should be able to handle the data model as it sees fit.  It's not really business logic that we're talking here, and I don't want to have to jump into the controller code to see what class is being passed.

If you are making use of this conditional all over the place, though, it certainly would make sense to at least create some convenience methods in the controller: isCarSuv(), isBus(), etc.  Then the ng-class conditional blocks would be cleaner.

```
<span ng-class="{'car-icon': isCarSuv(),'bus-icon': isBus(),'bike-icon': isBike()}">
```

I don't really think a pure B style implementation is the way I would do it.

Just my two cents. Others are sure to disagree.

Comment: I really like this implementation because we let the template manages its classes alone according to a context, **but** the rules that defines this context are placed in controller, which I think is a very good point. Moreover, readability is perfect : "applying bus-icon class if isBus() returns true" etc...

Answer (score 0):

I always use this variant since it is way cleaner, but i guess this is from developer to developer different

```
  <span ng-class="categoryIcon">
```